# Facebook app requesting personal data

Tags: facebook, privacy

I have to create a Facebook app for an online contest, and I need to collect users personal data through a form.

I have a checkbox for privacy with the link to the privacy agreement, but I heard that Facebook needs to approve your app if you're requesting personal data.
Is it true? What's the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you need more info than the `public_profile, user_friends, email` permissions, you have to submit your app for review. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login for a process description.

And, first of all, you'll have to implement the OAuth Login Flow (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.0) for your app, because otherwise you'll not be able to request any non-public data from your users.

Comment: Ok, I read it and it talks about Facebook data ("Extended Profile Properties"), but what I have in my app is a form when people directly insert their data (Name, Surname, Date of birth, etc), ticking a checkbox that allows us to manage their data (just in order to choose the winner of the contest). 
So, do I still need to send an approval request?

Comment: Why would you have to do that if the data isn't pulled from Facebook? Besides that, I somehow don't understand why people need to fill in the data manually, when you also could use FB functionality to do that. It's a bit strange...

Comment: A lot of people don't put their address or date of birth on Facebook, some don't even have their real name; but we want to let them participate in this contest, as long as they put real data in the form.

Comment: True, but a lot of such applications use the FB API to pre-populate the form with the given FB data. The user then can overwrite the pieces he wants to change.

Comment: And if your app is a canvas app, you could use the `signed_request` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) to get the user_id and then query the public_profile data, such as first and last name

Comment: Thank you for your help, and you are right about pre-populating data; but if I don't want to use FB data and I want to directly ask the users, I still don't know if I need that approval.

Comment: As I wrote: No. You don't pull any data from FB.